# How display a dialog box to wait for a program to be opened when it is launched via subprocess?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, subprocess

I'm using the subprocess function in order to open a Qt windows and I would like display a dialogbox (saying wait a minute for instance) that appear only the time for MyWindow is taking to be completely open.
I use that line to open my Qt window:

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "MyWindow.py"])
```

But I have no idea of how I can get a signal that MyWindow is open and so I could closed the qdialogue box in the first program (from which the subprocess is called).

Any idea?

Comment: What is the point of using `subprocess`? Just import *MyWindow.py* and open the window normally.

Comment: Because for now I run .py script but in the end I will launch .exe. When so, I could not import MyWindows directly.

Comment: Why can't you import it? Please edit your question and explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve, and make sure you include **all** the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about qt much, i am sure you must have gone through below link where users have faced similar problems

https://forum.qt.io/topic/6386/how-can-i-check-if-qmainwindow-is-fully-loaded

two things i can suggest

1) either use sleep to wait

2) you can use win32 api for python ,  which gives few controls over the window gui (get title,handle id) bases on your gui , you can play with the API and see if you can put some conditional wait.
here is one of many link on that topic

[Get the title of a window of another program using the process name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278590/get-the-title-of-a-window-of-another-program-using-the-process-name)