# Issues Adding Variable To getWindowsWithTitle

Tags: python, pycharm, pywin32

So I am having issues with getWindowsWithTitle function from pygetwindow. When I ask for input before the getWindowsWithTitle call, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****\main.py", line 79, in <module>
    handle.activate()
  File "*****\venv\lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 246, in activate
    _raiseWithLastError()
  File "*****\venv\lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 99, in _raiseWithLastError
    raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' % (errorCode, _formatMessage(errorCode)))
pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - The operation completed successfully.
```

If I comment out my Input call, the getWindowsWithTitle works just fine. The following is my code so far

```
import win32gui
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import pygetwindow as window


target = input("** Instance Name Is The Title When You Hover Over The Application ** \nSelect Instance Name: ")
handle = window.getWindowsWithTitle('Command')[0]

keyboard = Controller()
handle.activate()
handle.maximize()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.release('a')
```

I am trying to get input to choose which window to select, but even putting "target" in the getWindowsWithTitle it gives me the same error. Does anyone know why I am getting this error after putting in my input?

Comment: Anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've briefly looked a bit over [[GitHub]: asweigart/PyGetWindow - PyGetWindow](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow). I strongly suggest against using it as it's buggy (at least the current version):

1. Major, generic, conceptual flaw. It uses *CTypes*, but in an incorrect manner. I wonder how come there aren't a lot of bugs submitted against it. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011) for more details
2. In your particular case, an exception is raised. That behavior is incorrect (you get **error code *0*, which means success (*ERROR_SUCCESS*)**). [[MS.Docs]: SetForegroundWindow function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) doesn't specify using *GetLastError* if the function fails (doesn't do what it should). It's just the window couldn't be brought to front because of some of the mentioned reasons

Since you tagged your question for *PyWin32*, you could use that.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import pynput
import win32con as wcon
import win32gui as wgui


# Callback
def enum_windows_proc(wnd, param):
    if wgui.IsWindowVisible(wnd):
        text = wgui.GetWindowText(wnd)
        if param[0] in text.upper():
            print(wnd, text)  # Debug purposes only
            param[1].append(wnd)


def windows_containing_text(text):
    ret = []
    wgui.EnumWindows(enum_windows_proc, (text.upper(), ret))
    return ret


def send_char(wnd, char):
    kb = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
    kb.press(char)
    kb.release(char)


def main(*argv):
    txt = input("Enter text contained by window title: ")
    #txt = "notepad"
    wnds = windows_containing_text(txt)
    print(wnds)
    wnd = wnds[1]  # Notepad in my case (this example only, list might have fewer elements!!!!!)
    try:
        wgui.SetForegroundWindow(wnd)  # Activate
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
    wgui.ShowWindow(wnd, wcon.SW_MAXIMIZE)  # Maximize
    time.sleep(1)
    send_char(wnd, "a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Check [[SO]: Get the title of a window of another program using the process name (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278590/get-the-title-of-a-window-of-another-program-using-the-process-name/31280850#31280850) for more details on this *WinAPI* area.

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070373526]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Enter text contained by window title: notepad
> 394988 e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070373526\code00.py - Notepad++ [Administrator]
> 4264044 *Untitled - Notepad
> [394988, 4264044]
>
> Done.
> ```

**And an "*a*" *char* is inserted in the *Notepad* window at cursor position.**

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very helpful. So as I was running through your code I ran into a couple of things on my end. First if I just have 1 copy of an item open wnd = wnds[1] errors out to the index being out of bounds so I changed it to wnd = wnds[0]. Now I seem to be running into "pywintypes.error: (126, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'The specified module could not be found.')"

Comment: Interesting, I found if I do the send_char command before and after the setting of the windows, it works just fine, but if I don't do it before, SetForegroundWindow errors out.

Comment: `wnd = wnds[1]  # Notepad in my case` as the comment suggests it's in my case and it was particularly for this example, where the list had 2 entries. Regarding the errors you encounter, it's strange. I guess it depends on the window you want to activate, and also on the user type.