# Set alarm windows 10

Tags: python, clock, pywin32, alarm

How do I set an alarm using pywin32? I can't understand. Alarm returns None. If possible, then please in the example, I would appreciate it!

```
hTimer = win32event.CreateWaitableTimer(None, True,'test')

alarm = win32event.SetWaitableTimer(hTimer,10, 10, None, None, True)
```

Comment: Please add more details: the desired behavior and the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

Check [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) ((officially) referenced by [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)).

The supplied arguments are not correct (they are not incorrect *per se* but from expected outcome *PoV*). Check [[MS.Docs]: SetWaitableTimer function (synchapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer) for more details.

Unfortunately, the *PyWin32* wrapper doesn't handle the callback feature (*None* must be supplied), so the usecases are reduced (although it didn't happen in the question).

Here's how it can be used.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time

import win32api as wapi
import win32event as wevt


SEC = 10000000


def main(*argv):
    timer = wevt.CreateWaitableTimer(None, True, "Test")
    due = 2
    period = 500
    print("Setting timer to {:.3f} seconds".format(due))
    wevt.SetWaitableTimer(timer, due * -SEC, period, None, None, True)
    time_start = time.time()
    res = wevt.WaitForSingleObject(timer, -1)
    print("{:.3f} seconds elapsed. Result: {:d}".format(time.time() - time_start, res))
    wapi.CloseHandle(timer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073524234]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Setting timer to 2.000 seconds
> 2.001 seconds elapsed. Result: 0
>
> Done.
> ```

If you want a callback function to be automatically called at a given interval, you could use *PyWin32*'s *Timer* module.

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import msvcrt
import sys
import time

import timer as wtmr
import win32con as wcon
import win32gui as wgui


def timer_callback(tid, tm):
    print("Timer callback ({:}, {:}): {:}".format(tid, tm, time.gmtime()))


def main(*argv):
    due = 1
    print("Setting timer to {:.3f} seconds. Press a key to stop...".format(due))
    timer = wtmr.set_timer(due * 1000, timer_callback)
    while not msvcrt.kbhit():
        msg = wgui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        if msg[0] != -1 and msg[1][1] == wcon.WM_TIMER:
            wgui.DispatchMessage(msg[1])
    wtmr.kill_timer(timer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073524234]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code01.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Setting timer to 1.000 seconds. Press a key to stop...
> Timer callback (29224, 174310765): time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=6, tm_min=4, tm_sec=27, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
> Timer callback (29224, 174311765): time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=6, tm_min=4, tm_sec=28, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
> Timer callback (29224, 174312765): time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=6, tm_min=4, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
> Timer callback (29224, 174313765): time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=6, tm_min=4, tm_sec=30, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
> Timer callback (29224, 174314765): time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=6, tm_min=4, tm_sec=31, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
>
> Done.
> ```

**Note**: There is another way of calling *SetWaitableTimer* with a callback. It can be done via [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), but requires lots of boilerplate code and *C* knowledge. [[SO]: Get the title of a window of another program using the process name (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31280850/4788546) contains code using both *PyWin32* and *CTypes*, you could check the differences between them.

Comment: is it possible to somehow record an alarm clock in windows so that at the end a notification of the windows itself about the time comes out?
'built-in clock in windows 10'

Comment: I don't understand the question.  In both examples when time elapses, you could do whatever you want (I displayed a text, but you could display an image, play a song, ...).