SetClipboardData can't write any data
I am trying to write HTML to the clipboard as rich text, but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong? I tried running html_to_clipboard separately, but the clipboard is empty. SetClipboardData does not insert any text into it. However, copy_to_clipboard can write text successfully. Is there a step missing?
Note: If I comment out
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(CF_HTML, text.encode('utf-8'))

and add print(clipboard_data.decode('utf-8')), it can capture the content of the rich text properly, but SetClipboardData does not work and can't write any data...
import win32con
import win32clipboard,win32

text = '''Version:1.0
    StartHTML:0000000128
    EndHTML:0000000371
    StartFragment:0000000128
    EndFragment:0000000371
    SourceURL:about:blank
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><div style="background-color:#1e1f22;color:#bcbec4"><pre style="font-family:'JetBrains Mono',monospace;font-size:9.8pt;">xt()</pre></div></body></html> '''
result = 'Some Text'

def copy_to_clipboard():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(result, win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)
    if clipboard_data.decode('utf-8') == result:
        print('Copied to clipboard successfully')
    else:
        print('Failed to copy to clipboard')
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

def html_to_clipboard():
    CF_HTML = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format")

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(CF_HTML, bytearray(text, 'utf-8'))
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(CF_HTML)
    # print(clipboard_data.decode('utf-8'))
    if clipboard_data.decode('utf-8') == text:
        print('Copied HTML to clipboard successfully')
    else:
        print('Failed to copy HTML to clipboard')
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # copy_to_clipboard()
    html_to_clipboard()

it return:
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\python311\python.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Personal_scripts\pythonProject\temp.py 
Copied HTML to clipboard successfully

But the clipboard is blank in Win+V, and it can't paste any text.
Python: 3.11
OS:Windows10 Enterprise 21H2
Code Editor:Pycharm community
I tried: https://gist.github.com/Erreinion/6691093
But it don't work either. The clipboard is blank in Win+V too.

What do you get back?  Is there anything in clipboard_data?  Does the SetClipboardData call succeed?  You aren't checking for errors.

@TimRoberts The output of clipboard_data and text are essentially the same, but PyCharm tells me that clipboard_data and text are inconsistent, and furthermore, I cannot paste from the clipboard. When I use the Win+V shortcut key, the clipboard appears to be blank. (Pycharm did not report any errors.)

Windows can't paste formats it doesn't understand, and yours is an unknown format.  It might be a binary type, for all Windows knows.

@TimRoberts I added bytearray(text, 'utf-8'), although Pycharm told me successfully, but I can't paste text because the clipboard is blank in Win+V. What could be the cause?

I told you.  Windows doesn't know what CF_HTML means, so it can't show you anything.  It doesn't know how to interpret that type.  When an app tries to pull the clipboard, it has to tell Windows what formats it wants.  If the app doesn't ask for CF_HTML, it's not going to get any data.

@TimRoberts Can't I inform the system about by using the RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format") function from the pywin32 library? If the clipboard format cannot be registered, Pycharm should not return "successfully"...

Of course it can be registered, and other apps can fetch it by asking for CF_HTML, but it's a private format that YOU defined.  Only YOUR apps can handle it.  No one else has any idea what's inside it.  If you want a format that can be used generically, then use a generic format, not a custom one.

@TimRoberts I'm not sure where to find the information on valid clipboard formats. I came across the CF_HTML registered format in code related to rich text on the internet. However, I couldn't find any HTML-related formats in the win32con module of the pywin32 library.

(CF_HTML value is 49433, EnumClipboardFormats function enumerates clipboard formats including 49433). I couldn't find any relevant information online. Can you provide any relevant information?

There is no standard format called CF_HTML.  Format 49433 did not exist until YOU created it with RegisterClipboardFormat and the system assigned the next available number.  Once you register it, other applications can look up the same number, but no other application knows what it means.  It goes away when you reboot.  You could have done CF_FOOBAR = RegisterClipboardFormat("Bleen blark"); and you would get exactly the same results.

@TimRoberts Thank you for explaining CF_HTML. I must register the clipboard format, otherwise I cannot obtain the clipboard content related to HTML. I reference this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838210/how-to-get-and-set-non-standard-formats-to-clipboard-using-python-win32clipboar  By enumerating clipboard formats with GetClipboardFormatName, I can obtain the corresponding format names, which will facilitate registering the format next time to access the clipboard content. As for custom clipboard format registration, I need to gain a deeper understanding.

Refer to the third-party library "klembord" that supports rich text input. I adjusted the code and added SetClipboardText(unicode_text, CF_UNICODETEXT). The clipboard successfully reads the desired content. Win+V will display unicode_text instead of RTF, even though it displays as blank. If unicode_text is blank, I able to paste RTF content correctly in a RTF editor, but unable to paste unicode_text.
from re import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import win32clipboard

text = '''Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000105
EndHTML:0000000272
StartFragment:0000000141
EndFragment:0000000236
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><p style="font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;" id="20240514135730-37ivg0u" updated="20240514135730"><span data-type="code">loop</span></p>
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>'''


def html_to_clipboard():
    CF_HTML = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format")

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(CF_HTML, text.encode('utf-8'))
    unicode_text ='loop'
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(unicode_text, win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(CF_HTML)
    print("HTML：\n"+clipboard_data.decode('utf-8'))
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    print("TEXT：\n"+clipboard_data)

def get_clipboard():
    CF_HTML = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format")

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(CF_HTML)
    clipboard_data=BeautifulSoup(search('<!--StartFragment-->([\\s\\S]+)<!--EndFragment-->|<html>([\\s\\S]+)</html>',clipboard_data.decode('utf-8')).group(0),'lxml').prettify()
    print("HTML：\n"+clipboard_data)
    clipboard_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    print("TEXT：\n"+clipboard_data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

html_to_clipboard()
# get_clipboard()

